# How to hide html areas depending on user in Rails 4?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a checkout button on my product page show view which accepts the offer. Each offer belongs_to a user. I don't want the user who created the offer to be able to accept it themselves so if it is the current user on the page I want to hide the button. I can't figure out why this code doesn't work:

```
<% unless current_user.id == @offer.sender_id %> #sender_id is a foreign key in the offer model that makes each offer belong_to a user.

<div id="accept_offer">
  <%= button_to 'Accept Offer', etc  %>
</div>
    <% end %>
```

current_user is a devise gem method I believe.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Since that code does look right, I'm guessing your problem lies somewhere else :)

Comment: try to stop with a debugger just before the unless and check your variables.

Comment: If your relationships are setup correctly, you can clean up a bit with `current_user == @offer.sender`, btw

Comment: Could you specify the error instead of "does't work"?

Comment: Ok thanks all, the error is that it doesn't hide the button. I've tested this by running just "unless current_user" and that does hide the button.

Comment: So you tried that without sign in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code seems correct, you maybe need to look into your Offer.sender_id attribute in the model to see if it contains the right user id (of the creator of the offer). You could check that by creating a new offer throught your application (in the browser) then, in the console you type:

```
Offer.last.sender_id
```

And check if it corresponds to your current_user id

Comment: Ok I've found the inconsistency - for some reason the current user i.e. me had a different user_id to the sender_id number which is why the button remained visible. After resetting the user and offer objects I managed to get these in sync again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just saw the error and got the reason.

You tried the page without sign in so `unless current_user` works, this means you have not signed in. Your original code doesn't considered this case.

Generally you should see an error as current_user is not defined but you may have disabled that.

Two ways to fix:

1. Change current_user, assign an object in any case

   ```
   class ApplicationController
     def current_user
       super || User.new
     end
   end
   ```
2. Change the logic

   ```
   <% if current_user && current_user != @obj.sender %> 
     # Button code
     # Only signed in user with different id can see it
   ```